# Правильно ли оформил метод проверки наличия в базе данных информации по запросу

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Кажется логичным сперва сделать метод, который проверит, есть ли что то по запросу в базе и вернет true или false, а потом выполнять метод, который возвращает данные. Но в этом конкретном случае, проверка наличия в базе информации по запросу, осуществляется аж в строке `c.moveToFirst()` . Этот код ставит курсор в начало и если вдруг курсор пустой вернет false. И вот получается, что у меня уже в руках есть данные и зачем мне возвращать true, а потом делать еще один метод,который проделает еще раз эту работу. И я в случае истины возвращаю требуемую строку, а если по запросу ничего нет возвращаю строку "0" . А на выходе сам метод проверяется, если `if(!(GetAnswer.equals("0")))` .  Вопрос в том, правильно ли так всё организовать или есть более простой способ проверить наличие в данных по запросу. Думаю что нет и я прав)

```
 String getAnswer(String strDate, String currency) {
                long unixTimeDate = 1;
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
                    format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date = format.parse(strDate);
                    unixTimeDate = date.getTime();

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Cursor c = exchangeRatesDatabase.query("ExchangeRatesTable",
                        new String[]{"json"},
                        "date = ?",
                        new String[]{Long.toString(unixTimeDate)},
                        null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int idColJson = c.getColumnIndex("json");
                    String answer = c.getString(idColJson);
                    c.close(); 
                    return answer;
                }
                return "0";
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если из метода требуется возвратить результат, с контролем, что этот результат имеется, то лучше в качестве неудачной выборки возвращать `null`/ Это гарантирует, что данные не смогут перекрываться с меткой о неудачной попытке (в качестве результата может быть возвращено 0), проверка на null будет выполнена быстрее вызова метода сравнения и просто интуитивно понятнее, глядя на код, что мы проверяем и зачем (так же немного упростил само выражение проверки и к тому же по возможности стоит избегать нескольких точек выхода из метода):

```
String getAnswer(String strDate, String currency) {
            long unixTimeDate = 1;
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
                format.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date date = format.parse(strDate);
                unixTimeDate = date.getTime();

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Cursor c = exchangeRatesDatabase.query("ExchangeRatesTable",
                    new String[]{"json"},
                    "date = ?",
                    new String[]{Long.toString(unixTimeDate)},
                    null, null, null);

            if (с != null) {
                 String answer = (c.moveToFirst())? c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("json")): null;
                 c.close();
            }
            return answer;

}
```

проверка:

```
if (getAnswer() != null) { // обрабатываем результат) };
```

Дополнение: `if (c.moveToFirst()) {// курсор не пустой }` - вполне рабочий способ проверить курсор на наличие данных, если вам так же нужно установить его на первую строку (это не всегда требуется).

Другие способы проверить курсор на наличие данных:

`if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {// курсор не пустой }`

Вообще, практически стандартный паттерн прочитать курсор (в том числе с несколькими записями):

```
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // извлечение данных из курсора
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вообще вопрос больше о том правильна ли задумка с вызовом метода, который вернет нужную строку в случае наличия данных в таблице,  а в случае отсутствия вернет ''0''. Правильно ли и в плане производительности и в плане читабельности

Comment: @Turalllb а, в вопросе не очень понятно, что именно это вы имели ввиду. Дополнил.

Comment: pavlofff, вот теперь то что надо. Только я не понял как вы избавились от нескольких точек выхода. Если перевести на человеческий язык в return вы написали: Если курсор не null и если опять же курсор не null, поставить в начало строки курсор (тут наверно можно избавиться от второго выражения? так как у меня всего одна строка всегда в курсоре)  выполнить возврат строки , иначе вернуть null. Логика ясна, только я первый раз вижу использование знака вопроса и двоеточния в таком смысле. Где можно глянуть про подобный синтаксис?  Получается все равно что оператор if , но дважды не написано return

Comment: и пока не пойму почему, но этот return всегда возвращает null..

Comment: насчет самого оператора я нашел: тернарный оператор. А вот почему он возвращает null всё время не пойму.

Comment: а в старом коде работало как надо?

Comment: Всё работает. Затупил. Я думал ночью кое что изменил, а оказывается нет.  Я понял что в моем случае курсор надо ставить в начало, иначе получаю ошибку, только не понял почему, если там всего одна запись. Наверно курсор стоит в конце записи и надо вперед выставить его?

Comment: И еще мы выходим из метода не закрыв курсор c.close  .  При выходе из метода он итак сам по себе закроется и освободит ресурс?

Comment: сразу после выборки курсор стоит **перед** первой записью и его надо обязательно установить куда-то прежде, чем получать значения. нет, курсор сам не закроется, об этом я не подумал.

Comment: pavlofff, наверно стоит добавить строку if (с != null) c.clouse  или вообще вернуться к if вместо тернарного оператора.  Студия предупреждает, что курсор может быть null/